# Caesar Cipher: I want to shift user input (plaintext) "n" number of times

Tags: java, encryption, caesar-cipher

```
/**
 *
 * @author hamza
 */
public class Caesar_Chipher {


    // This is where I call my functions 
    public static void main(String[] args) {     
        userChoice();
    }



    //User chooses 1 or 2 to encrypt or decrypt
    public static void userChoice() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        System.out.print("Enter your choice, 1 = encrypt, 2 = decrypt: ");
        int userchoice; 
        userchoice = input.nextInt();
        if (userchoice == 1) {
            offsetNumber();
            message();
            System.out.println(plaintext + shift);
        }

        if (userchoice == 2) {
            offsetNumber();
            message();
            System.out.println(plaintext + shift);
        }

        else {
            userChoice();
        }
    }

    public static void offsetNumber() {
        Scanner offset = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your shift number: ");
        int shift;
        shift = offset.nextInt();
        if (shift < 27) {
            message();
        }
    }

    public static void message() {
        Scanner Message = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter your message: ");
        String plaintext;
        plaintext = Message.next();
    }        
}
```

What is wrong with my code? When someone encrypts I want the plaintext to be shifted by n and when someone decrypts I want the plaintext to be shifted by -n.

Comment: No offense, but you should really take a look at how procedural code flow works and what return and the respective return-types do(es). You need to pass variables from one method to another, this is not done for you, because you would otherwise be very limited in general with instance/local variables. You could start [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm).

Comment: I know what return types do

Comment: but i dont know how to pass variables

Comment: @Hamza You should study about passing arguments (variables) to methods. Search youtube for some good videos.

Comment: Look at the link i supplied in my comment. IMO, that is a good explanation.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to add a description of your problem with the code. We can only help with specific problems and we're not here to fix everything with your code. You need to describe how your code is behaving and how you want it to behave.

Answer (score 0):

This is not yet a full answer but commenting doesn't support multiple lines for this code example.

The return keyword gives the variable back to the caller of the method. Thus, in the following example `returnMeAnInt()` will be replaced with 4 when the code is executed. However, there is a lot more to it (and especially instance and local variables), so a stack overflow answer can't teach you the basics of java. Go and search for tutorials - or even better: a good book.

```
void main(String[] args) {
    int i = returnMeAnInt();
    System.out.println(i); // will print 4
}

int returnMeAnInt() {
    return 4;
}
```